# Defining a ForEach function

Tags: evaluation, function-construction

Consider the following function definition:

`ForEach[iterators__] := Table[#, iterators] &;`

Two questions about it:

I. It works perfectly if you call it like `ForEach[{m,3},{n,3}]@{m,n}` and outputs:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{1,1\} & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} \\
 \{2,1\} & \{2,2\} & \{2,3\} \\
 \{3,1\} & \{3,2\} & \{3,3\}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

However, the result of `ForEach[{m, 3}, {n, 3}]@ToString[m n]` is:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{m n} & \text{m n} & \text{m n} \\
 \text{m n} & \text{m n} & \text{m n} \\
 \text{m n} & \text{m n} & \text{m n}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Why it doesn't treat `m` and `n` as known variables?

II. How can I pass a piece of code to the function to be run before each iteration? For instance, I want to call the function with an option like `k=0; ForEach[{m, 3}, {n, 3},Pre->k++]@{k,m,n}` which is the same as `k = 0; Table[k++; {k, m, n}, {m, 3}, {n, 3}]`?

Comment: This question was asked in variations on SO before: e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160216/foreach-loop-in-mathematica), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181470/custom-function-with-non-standard-evaluation-behaves-like-table), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911827/non-standard-evaluation-and-packedarray). You may find those discussions interesting, if not exactly addressing your particular question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key here is learning about evaluation control.  Please see the tutorials linked from [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/EvaluationControl.html).

---

Use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TracePrint.html) to see how it is evaluated and you'll understand.

In

```
ForEach[{m, 3}, {n, 3}]@ToString[m n]
```

`ToString[m n]` is evaluated to `"m n"` before `ForEach` even sees it.  Also, if `m` or `n` have values, this'll break.  Set a `HoldAll` attribute in the function:

```
ClearAll[ForEach]
SetAttributes[ForEach, HoldAll]
ForEach[iterators__] := Function[arg, Table[arg, iterators], HoldAll]
```

---

For the second part simply requires [learning about option handling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html):

```
ClearAll[ForEach]
SetAttributes[ForEach, HoldAll]
Options[ForEach] = {Pre -> Null}
ForEach[iterators__, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Function[arg, Table[OptionValue[Pre]; arg, iterators], HoldAll]

k = 0
ForEach[{n, 3}, {m, 3}, Pre :> k++][ToString@{m, n, k}]
```

---

Making this is good as a learning exercise, but I find this construct problematic and fragile.  If you want to use this to solve actual problems, other approaches are better.  Why don't you describe the problem that you want to solve?

Comment: `Pre :> k++` is the trick for the second part. I just missed it.

Comment: @Mohsen Read about evaluation control in the link I included at the top.

Comment: The problem is quite technical and not very "Mathematical". I have already solved the problem but I am looking for ways to make the code more readable. The problem is that I have too many/long nested calls which makes the code somewhat hard to read, specially for non-programmers. I want to write some function to make a DSL out of Mathematica. Then, I want to use the DSL to make my code more human  understandable.

Comment: I probably should not be saying this, but I find the doc tutorials on evaluation rather useless for beginners. In my opinion, evaluation should be discussed in a coherent manner, *explaining* the role of various constructs by showing how they affect the evaluation sequence, rather than just listing some of their properties. Otherwise, you just create some magic spells, and multiply entities, precisely opposite to the Occam's razor principle. Within the currently existing literature, the best account on evaluation is IMO chapter 7 of David Wagner's book, which I can't recommend highly enough.

Comment: @Leonid Feel free to edit my answer with links or add a completely new one. I'll be glad to recommend it. I am trying to reduce my participation these days (with difficulty), it's hurting my productivity--so I can't improve on the answer now.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am in the same boat - perhaps more than it may be apparent, but you may have noticed that I already reduced my activity here.

Comment: @Leonid Why not to say it, it's true. It's a shame Wagner's book seems unobtainable (amazon says "from $609 from these sellers", which is even worse than the last few times I looked) and there seems to be no very good, extensive tutorial easily available.

Comment: @acl I have a chapter in the book I am working on, devoted to this, which is supposed to fill this gap. It is largely written by now (actually, has been already for a while). On some occasion, I may make another long post (hopefully my last of this kind) here on SE, trying to make a brief but reasonably complete tutorial on this matter. That's a lot of work for this particular topic, however, and I'm pretty tied up for at least a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Leonid that would be nice. Also, one should keep in mind that perfection is the enemy of the good; maybe you could put these articles on your website while the book is ongoing, and mark them as work in progress? This way we won't have to go through your papers if something happens (you get bored, abducted by aliens etc), like with Ramanujan :)

Comment: @acl That's a good point :). Usually, the problem is however, that I always have so many things to do. I have a number of  ongoing projects (going quite slowly, the book is one of them). Whenever I have a choice between posting and development, I usually prefer development. I actually spent much more time here already than I could afford, at the expense of some important (to me) things, and will have to reduce my presense here. But some questions on SO  prompt me to switch and post, because I perceive them as the demand by the community, which I consider more objective than my own opinions.

Comment: @acl These are those "long posts" for which I became notorious here :). Part of my motivation for doing them is to provide the community with comprehensive answers (as much as I am able to) to questions I consider important / essential, to counter the "magic spell" approach to coding, which I deeply dislike and consider harmful. A good thing about SE is that it has post length limitations, so I have to be necessarily more brief than I'd be otherwise (for example, recent meta-programming question would requite much more thorough account to *really* give it justice), which I think is good.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but what about [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)/[`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html), which are pretty much the functional equivalents to `ForEach` constructs?

```
data = Table[{m, n}, {m, 3}, {n, 3}]
k = 0
Map[Prepend[#, ++k] &, data, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}}, {{4, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 2}, {6, 2, 3}}, {{7, 3, 1}, {8, 3, 2}, {9, 3, 3}}}
> ```

Or alternatively, using no state variable,

```
MapIndexed[Prepend[#, 3 (#2[[1]] - 1) + #2[[2]]] &, data, {2}]
```

> (same output)

Comment: As I described in the comment under Szabolcs's answer, I need the ForEach construct to improve the readability of a piece of code for non-programmers. Otherwise, there are many other ways to get the job done.